# Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. If $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to $Y^{\mathbb{N}}$ is $X$ homemorphic to $Y^k$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. If $X^{\mathbb{N}}$ is homeomorphic to $Y^{\mathbb{N}}$ (product topology) is $X$ homemorphic to $Y^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ or $k = \mathbb{N}$?

We must allow the possibility of $k = \mathbb{N}$ since the countable product of a Cantor set is a Cantor set.

Comment: No. Take $X$ to consist of $2$ elements and $Y$ to consist of $3$. (Presumably you also wanted to allow for the possibility that $Y$ is homeomorphic to a power of $X$.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you. What if we do not allow $X$ or $Y$ to be finite sets?

Comment: There are still other examples, for instance, $X=[0,1]^2$ and $Y=[0,1]^3$. So you also need to allow that $X^j$ is homeomorphic to $Y^k$.

Comment: Neither of those additions are enough; now you can take $X = [0, 1] \sqcup [0 ,1]$ and $Y = [0, 1] \sqcup [0, 1] \sqcup [0, 1]$.